# persistedoffset is in an unexpected state with some lottie assets

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, lottie

I'm encountering an issue in my project where the error message "persistedoffset is in an unexpected state" is being triggered for certain Lottie files. Strangely, some Lottie files work correctly while others do not. I'm uncertain whether the problem lies in the Lottie files themselves or in the structure of my code. I've inspected the file integrity, compared working and non-working files, updated the Lottie library, and reviewed the animation initialization process. Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I'm seeking guidance on troubleshooting this specific error. Could you provide insights into common pitfalls or steps I might be overlooking to identify and resolve the problem with the 'persistedoffset' variable? Any assistance or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```
Container(
            height: 500,
            child: Lottie.network(
              'https://lottie.host/4c0ebeb4-bec8-4cd2-a936-7fc2ad2e5e75/iMO8e1CyUB.json',
            ),
          
          ),
```

i am expecting lottie working in all files or issue with all files